# How to alter column datatype without dropping a constraint?

Tags: sql-server

I want to alter column datatype

```
ALTER TABLE Expense ALTER COLUMN TotalQty decimal(10,2) not null;
```

but I'm getting the error

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State I, Line I The object 'DF Expense TotalQt 34
>   g3CFA7' is dependent on column ' TotalQty' . Msg 4922, Level 16, State
>   9, Line 1 ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUtvm TotalQty failed because one or
>   more objects access this column.

I know that I can do

```
alter table CompanyTransactions drop constraint [df__CompanyTr__Creat__0cdae408];
```

but how can I alter the column datatype without dropping the constraint?

Comment: why not to drop this constraint, then alter your column and finally recreate that constraint?

Comment: Quite simply, you can't. And that's a good thing because there's no reason to assume the old default value would even be appropriate. The engineers could have gone the extra mile and verified that so you wouldn't get the message if there was no problem, but they didn't.